# Maven Eclipse plugin installation

Tags: eclipse, plugins, maven, build, eclipse-plugin

Is there any where i can download the maven eclipse plugin so that i can install it manually without using an update site? 
The download site for the plugin http://eclipse.org/m2e/download/ only provides information of how to download it directly from the Eclipse IDE but not how to download it as a Zip file.

I need to install it on a Server that has no connectivity to the outside world so i need to download it as a zip archive then install it manually.

Thanks

### Edit

I also found out that the Maven plugin comes pre-packaged with Eclipse for JAVA developers but not Eclipse for JAVA EE developers. (Which is the one i am using).

### Edit

@Soulcheck - I tried your suggestion but it is coming up with an error. The command i used is

```
java -jar -DproxySet=true  -DproxyHost=myproxyHost -DproxyPort=8080 plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar -application  org.eclipse.update.core.standaloneUpdate -command mirror -from http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases -to C:\wresource\home\res.nosynch\temp.todel\m2e
```

I added the options for the proxy as that is required to get an external connection. The error is shown below: Do you think that maybe the URL is wrong?

```
!SESSION 2012-02-01 16:14:08.581 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=M20110909-1335
java.version=1.6.0_29
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_GB
Framework arguments:  -application org.eclipse.update.core.standaloneUpdate -command mirror -from http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases -to C:\wresource\home\res.nosynch\temp.todel\m2e
Command-line arguments:  -application org.eclipse.update.core.standaloneUpdate -command mirror -from http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases -to C:\wresource\home\res.nosynch\temp.todel\m2e

!ENTRY org.eclipse.update.core 4 0 2012-02-01 16:14:12.213
!MESSAGE Unable to access "http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases".
!STACK 1
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Error parsing site stream. [The XML stream is not a valid default "site.xml" file. The root tag is not site.]
    at org.eclipse.update.core.Utilities.newCoreException(Utilities.java:225)
    at org.eclipse.update.core.Utilities.newCoreException(Utilities.java:256)
    at org.eclipse.update.core.model.SiteModelFactory.parseSite(SiteModelFactory.java:95)
    at org.eclipse.update.internal.core.SiteURLFactory.createSite(SiteURLFactory.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.update.internal.core.InternalSiteManager.createSite(InternalSiteManager.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.update.internal.core.InternalSiteManager.createSite(InternalSiteManager.java:326)
    at org.eclipse.update.internal.core.InternalSiteManager.createSite(InternalSiteManager.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.update.internal.core.InternalSiteManager.attemptCreateSite(InternalSiteManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.update.internal.core.InternalSiteManager.getSite(InternalSiteManager.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.update.core.SiteManager.getSite(SiteManager.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.update.internal.mirror.MirrorCommand.run(MirrorCommand.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.update.standalone.ScriptedCommand.run(ScriptedCommand.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.update.standalone.StandaloneUpdateApplication.run(StandaloneUpdateApplication.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: The XML stream is not a valid default "site.xml" file. The root tag is not site.
    at org.eclipse.update.core.model.DefaultSiteParser.handleInitialState(DefaultSiteParser.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.update.core.model.DefaultSiteParser.startElement(DefaultSiteParser.java:198)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.update.core.model.DefaultSiteParser.parse(DefaultSiteParser.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.update.core.model.SiteModelFactory.parseSite(SiteModelFactory.java:83)
    ... 28 more
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.update.core 4 0 2012-02-01 16:14:12.216
!MESSAGE Error parsing site stream. [The XML stream is not a valid default "site.xml" file. The root tag is not site.]
!STACK 0
org.xml.sax.SAXException: The XML stream is not a valid default "site.xml" file. The root tag is not site.
    at org.eclipse.update.core.model.DefaultSiteParser.handleInitialState(DefaultSiteParser.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.update.core.model.DefaultSiteParser.startElement(DefaultSiteParser.java:198)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.update.core.model.DefaultSiteParser.parse(DefaultSiteParser.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.update.core.model.SiteModelFactory.parseSite(SiteModelFactory.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.update.internal.core.SiteURLFactory.createSite(SiteURLFactory.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.update.internal.core.InternalSiteManager.createSite(InternalSiteManager.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.update.internal.core.InternalSiteManager.createSite(InternalSiteManager.java:326)
    at org.eclipse.update.internal.core.InternalSiteManager.createSite(InternalSiteManager.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.update.internal.core.InternalSiteManager.attemptCreateSite(InternalSiteManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.update.internal.core.InternalSiteManager.getSite(InternalSiteManager.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.update.core.SiteManager.getSite(SiteManager.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.update.internal.mirror.MirrorCommand.run(MirrorCommand.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.update.standalone.ScriptedCommand.run(ScriptedCommand.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.update.standalone.StandaloneUpdateApplication.run(StandaloneUpdateApplication.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.update.core 4 0 2012-02-01 16:14:12.218
!MESSAGE Error parsing site stream. [The XML stream is not a valid default "site.xml" file. The root tag is not site.]
!STACK 0
org.xml.sax.SAXException: The XML stream is not a valid default "site.xml" file. The root tag is not site.
    at org.eclipse.update.core.model.DefaultSiteParser.handleInitialState(DefaultSiteParser.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.update.core.model.DefaultSiteParser.startElement(DefaultSiteParser.java:198)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.update.core.model.DefaultSiteParser.parse(DefaultSiteParser.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.update.core.model.SiteModelFactory.parseSite(SiteModelFactory.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.update.internal.core.SiteURLFactory.createSite(SiteURLFactory.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.update.internal.core.InternalSiteManager.createSite(InternalSiteManager.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.update.internal.core.InternalSiteManager.createSite(InternalSiteManager.java:326)
    at org.eclipse.update.internal.core.InternalSiteManager.createSite(InternalSiteManager.java:298)
    at org.eclipse.update.internal.core.InternalSiteManager.attemptCreateSite(InternalSiteManager.java:222)
    at org.eclipse.update.internal.core.InternalSiteManager.getSite(InternalSiteManager.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.update.core.SiteManager.getSite(SiteManager.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.update.internal.mirror.MirrorCommand.run(MirrorCommand.java:78)
    at org.eclipse.update.standalone.ScriptedCommand.run(ScriptedCommand.java:66)
    at org.eclipse.update.standalone.StandaloneUpdateApplication.run(StandaloneUpdateApplication.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

### Edit

Ok i got it to work with the following command:

```
eclipse.exe -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.mirrorApplication -source http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases -destination file:C:\temp\m2e\
```

The above will put the contents into `c:\temp\m2e`. To install it manually on eclipse,
 - click on "Help" >> "install new Software". 
 - On the window that pops up click "Add" on the top right corner and on the next window that pops up click on "Local" and specify the path C:\temp\m2e\ and click OK and you are done! :)

Comment: are you sure, that you want the eclipse maven plugin and not maven itself for the server? http://maven.apache.org/download.html

Comment: Yes. I do have maven (standalone) installed separately. I need the plugin so that i can build directly from Eclipse.

Comment: eclipse plugin can be downloaded here: http://maven.apache.org/maven-1.x/plugins/eclipse/downloads.html

Comment: Those are plugins for Maven 1.x. They come bundled with Maven 1.x not 3.x :) Thanks.

Comment: I actually checked on my eclipse 4.2 installation and its maven plugin version is 1.0.100. But I guess you are right :)

Comment: @wuppi that's a maven plugin, not an eclipse plugin.

Comment: You said that you do not have a connectivity to outside world, but based on your edits, you do have if you just specify the proxy. So... which is it? If you define the proxy can you just install it the normal way?

Comment: Im using two machines. One with connectivity(via proxy) which i use to download the plugin. The plugin will then be ftp'ed to the other server which has no connectivity at all and the plugin will be installed manually on the server with no connectivity.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

m2e doesn't provide zipped update site, but you can try to mirror the official one locally and then use the mirror to install the features you need. [According to this doc](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/update_standalone.html) it should be as simple as:

```
 java -jar plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_<version>.jar
-application  org.eclipse.update.core.standaloneUpdate
-command mirror
-from update_site_url
-featureId id_of_the_feature 
-to your_local_dir
```

**edit2 eclipse indigo, etc** 
Ok looks like they changed things a bit. Now one should use p2 repository mirroring:

```
 eclipse -nosplash -verbose 
    -application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository.mirrorApplication 
    -source http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo 
    -destination file:/destination_dir 
    -ius org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group
```

As far as I can see `-ius` parameter doesn't work, so the whole repo is going to be mirrored.

It looks like [p2 ant tasks](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox/p2/Ant_Tasks) are the preffered way of creating mirrors, and supposedly they allow fine grained control on what is mirrored.

Comment: This is would be brilliant if i can download it. How do i know which version of the launcher to use? Thanks

Comment: @ziggy console autocompletion in eclipse root directory ;) for indigo i have it's 1.2.0.v20110502

Comment: Does this make any change to the local instance of eclipse?

Comment: no, that's what `-to` parameter is for. it just uses eclipse jar to download stuff.

Comment: @ziggy I updated the answer as the update site for m2e gave me err 404

Comment: Got it to work without the -ius argument. Thank you sir you have been very helpful.

Comment: Do i need the -ius argument? Where is this documented. Thanks

Comment: documentation is scarce, i once saw it on eclipse bug tracker and it seemed to limit mirrored feature to the ones specified with -ius parameter. unfortunately as far as i can see it doesn't work and it mirrors everything. Eclipse people recommend using p2 ant tasks to limit the mirror scope.